# get data from multidimensional json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to get the result of the following json object returned by google driving api.

```
"routes": [
    {
        "bounds": {
            "Ga": {
                "C": 39.01115,
                "j": 39.06483
            },
            "xa": {
                "j": -77.57857000000001,
                "C": -77.47601
            }
        },
        "copyrights": "Map data ©2015 Google",
        "legs": [
            {
                "distance": {
                    "text": "9.4 mi",
                    "value": 15096
                },
                "duration": {
                    "text": "15 mins",
                    "value": 870
                },
                "end_address":"1234 Any St USA".....//and so on
```

how would i go about getting the data in "text" or "end_address"

i have tried

```
 alert(result.routes.legs.distance.text)
```

and

```
 alert(result.routes.legs.end_address);
```

and i get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'distance' of undefined
```

and

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'end_address' of undefined
```

respectively

Comment: You're missing the array indexes. Don't you see the square brackets, which surround arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`routes` is an array and `legs` is an array within each of the `routes` array objects

Try

```
 alert(routes[0].legs[0].distance.text)
```

Comment: excellant, thank you.  I didn't realize that 0 was needed. Im used to seeing the key 0 like in php

Comment: handling is no different than in php really other than php doesn't have `dot` syntax

Comment: yea, in my mind i would expect to see "legs[0]: blah blah...

Comment: can write it exactly the same in javascript as php `routes[0]['legs'][0]['distance']['text']`

Comment: yea, the writing part makes sense.  the result shows "legs":[ blah blah.      im used to seeing "legs[0] blah blah...

Comment: well feel free to accept answer if it helped